# The verb "tune out" and the whole meaning of a headline

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/pound-forecasters-tune-boe-rate-050001945.html) now,

The headline says,

> Pound Forecasters **Tune Out** BOE Cut Calls to Sound Upbeat

Now after googling and looking up dictionaries of both the English-English and English-my country's language, the verb "tune out" turned out to be, sort of

> silence
>
> decrease the volume of

Now, the meaning of the headline is a bit complex to me.

Does the headline try to say,

"The currency forecasters (seemingly) ignore the BOE's rate cute to see the bullish pound in the future"?

Thank you for your support in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you got hold of "turn down." *Tune out* means to ignore. Your interpretation is correct modulo "cute" = *cut*. There's one bit of ambiguity: the headline could mean the currency speculators are tuning out the BOE for the purpose of sounding upbeat or  it could mean that they're doing their tuning out and they just so happen to thereby sound upbeat

Comment: @user105719 Thanks for enlightenment. But isn't the title too "cut" to get the meaning through at first glance? I did not need to look up the dictionary when I first read it, but it finally made me feel a bit complexed:)

Comment: Too cut? Cut, certainly because that's the compressed nature of headline English. It's hard for me to count glances from way over here, but I think it's clear from the article that the Pound Forecasters are ignoring the BOE's warning of cuts in the interest rate. And the headline reflects that. Is sounding upbeat the result of a deliberate strategy of ignoring the BOE or does that just happen to be the effect?That's harder to say.

Comment: @user105719 Kindly cool down, please? I beg you. I am not a native speaker, but let me thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm ice cold, thank you. I mostly agree with you. Sorry, if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct (and the headline is something of a [crash blossom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity#In_headlines): I had to read it a couple of times before I worked out how to parse it).

*Tune out* means "stop hearing [something] even though it's still there".